# Obtaining / resetting password from an MS SQL .BAK file?

Tags: sql-server

We have a client who wants us to extract data from their MS SQL bak file.  I've gone to restore it, but I'm just getting:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.ConnectionInfo)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Access is denied due to a password failure
RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3279)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.4053&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=3279&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

The password itself seems to have been set by the original software vendor, and so the client doesn't have it.

Is there any way I can reset or obtain this password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the SA password for the database?  Long shot, but they could be the same.  Try it with the following:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Northwind FROM DISK='C:\yourbackup.BAK' WITH MEDIAPASSWORD='thepassword'
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've got nothing but the .BAK file.  

Ridiculously, I can (should I really have the urge) open it as plain text and I can see the data, so it's not really encrypted or anything - it's just seemingly got a password purely stopping me from restoring the database.

Comment: Then to be honest I think this is one of those where you're just not going to be able to do it.  And as I am a lazy bugger, I'd have told the client that aaaages ago. ;)

Comment: Normally I would have, but I've come across this particular system previously, and I'm likely to again, so it'd make my life just that little bit easier if I had a reasonable way around this.

All I can think of at the moment is attempting to remotely connect to the client, installing server management studio, and exporting it directly from the data myself.

Comment: Or you could create a little console app that connects to the db and performs the backup. Saves installing sqlsms.

Answer (score -1):

Turn it off and back on again.

Comment: Standard IT answer which is certainly always worth a shot, and although I'm amused, I'm afraid I can't in good conscience give an up vote. Nice try though! :)